# Why UITableViewCell displays previous value at first and just later updates self?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, asynchronous, grand-central-dispatch

I have a UITableView with a UIImageView on it. On these imageViews I'm downloading images from the server and display them. The problem is that when I scroll my UITableView, at first it shows another cell's image and just later(in 2-3 seconds) it updates the cell's imageView to the properly image.

How can I fix it? I've tried to use background and main thread mix, like that:

```
extension UIImageView {
func getDataFromUrl(url:String, completion: ((data: NSData?) -> Void)) {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), {
        NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(NSURL(string: url)!) { (data, response, error) in
            completion(data: NSData(data: data!))
            }.resume()
    })
}

func downloadImage(url:String){
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), {
        self.getDataFromUrl(url) { data in
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                self.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFill
                self.image = UIImage(data: data!)
            }
        }
    })
}
}
```

and use these extension on my `cellForRowAtIndexPath` as:

```
cell.coverImage.downloadImage("\(credentials.postCoverURL)\(recentNews[indexPath.row].image)")
```

but it doesn't help me. It works as previously. What I do wrong? If you can, please give a description(explanation) to your answer. It will be more useful! Thanks!

**UPDATE**

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell: newsCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! newsCell
    cell.coverImage.downloadImage("\(credentials.postCoverURL)\(recentNews[indexPath.row].image)")

    return cell
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What is actually happening in your code is that all cells are given a reuse identifier, meaning that they all get put into the same object pool. This means that when you use [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: CustomCellIdentifier]; that you are retrieving a cell from this one pool. It already has a image set up which you need to clear.

Before setting up the cell to download Image you need to clear the image before.

```
cell.coverImage.image = nil
cell.coverImage.downloadImage("\(credentials.postCoverURL)\(recentNews[indexPath.row].image)")
```

Comment: Have you also added cell.coverImage.image = nil before downloadImage.

Comment: Try resetting here https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewCell_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableViewCell/prepareForReuse

Comment: didn't help at all =/

Comment: You can also try to set the image to any placeholder instead of nil or UIImage(). as i have came across this a lot and its the only way to solve it resetting the data.

Answer (score 0):

Let me explain the problem.

Imagine you have the first row, i call it ROW_A object. ROW_A should download and display image with URL_1, by using a thread THREAD_1. When it's in you `cellForRow` function, you started THREAD_1 to download the image for ROW_A

When you scroll, the first row become invisible, so the ROW_A view object will be reused for displaying another row, for example, row 11th. In the `cellForRow`, the same process as before, you started thread THREAD_11 to download the image with URL_11 and display that image using ROW_A object (as i said before, the ROW_A object is reused)

The problem is, after a long time downloading IMAGE_1 from URL_1, THREAD_1 finishes its works and set IMAGE_1 to ROW_A. You will see IMAGE_1 being showed.
After that, THREAD_11 finishes too, it set IMAGE_11 to the ROW_A. But ROW_A is displaying IMAGE_1, so that why you see IMAGE_1 then IMAGE_11 on row 11th.

To fix this problem, you should check the image view to see if it's assigned to other downloading thread. I mean, if THREAD_1 finish, THREAD_1 should know that ROW_A is not belong to THREAD_1 anymore. You can create a `UIImageView` subclass with a `url:String` property, then when the downloading thread finishes, you compare the url string of downloaded image with value of `url` property, if it's different, don't show the image.

Another option is using AFNetworking for downloading and showing the remote images. That's very simple and you can find many tutorial on Google.